# Online - User photo not updated in userphoto.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, user-profile

I'm using SharePoint Online and I'm trying to retrieve user photo making a request to `userphoto.aspx` with this URL:

```
var account = encodeURI(user@domain.tld);
return "https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname="+account;
```

For some users this is working fine and I see the image correctly, for others it keeps returning the image like it is missing (but I checked and user added its own user photo).

The user who I am checking has never opened the company SharePoint site.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck using the Graph for this. Create a REST request in the contaxt of the user. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
/me/photo/$value
```

or if it's for another user

```
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if images are present in SharePoint by using the below urls:

```
https://my-site-url/User Photos/Profile Pictures/david_contoso_onmicrosoft_com_MThumb.jpg

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='PictureURL')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
```

If still it does not return any pictur url, then I guess your sync between Exchange Online-SharePoint Online is broken. Check this article [information on the sync](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/information-about-profile-picture-synchronization-in-office-365-20594d76-d054-4af4-a660-401133e3d48a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Thank you. It seems if the user doesn't not open SharePoint Online, the photo still remains unavailable. Do you know if there's a way to force sync without force user to log in to SharePoint?

Comment: That is related to User Information List. And entry of the user is made only when user first time visits the site.

Comment: I've opened SharePoint Online with another user (that has set its photo and I can see that photo on top right corner). I've waited about 24 hours but photo is still not available with Userphoto.aspx